# How to add views to ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Controllers process requests and return views in ASP.NET MVC, but how to add presentation layer (views or html pages) in ASP.NET Core Web API? I need to show to the user not the `IEnumerable` collection of objects, but a real webpage. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: A view in MVC is the presentation layer. There are [many tutorials out there on how to get started with MVC Views in ASP.NET Core](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=asp.net+mvc+views+tutorial&ia=web). Try a couple and follow along. Come back if you get stuck and have a specific question.

Comment: @Igor i mean how to add view (or something like view) in a web api project (not mvc)

Comment: In .net core it is the same thing. You just add the nuget package for mvc and then you can create razor views (after a line or 2 of configuration in startup.cs). Again, follow a tutorial or read the docs to get started.

Answer (score 4):

Add MVC packages if not available from nuget package manager

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

add this line to startup.cs

```
//replace => services.AddControllers();
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

I hope you will be able to use MVC feature from now.